# iText Maximum Font Size

Tags: java, itext

I'm using a fixed cell height to create a table.
If the font size is too large, the text is not visible in the table.

Is there a built-in function in iText that automatically reduces the font size to the maximum possible size, or do I have to implement this by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic font size is only possible in the context of AcroForm text fields. When you define the font size of a text field as 0, then a font size is chosen that fits the rectangle. In the case of a fixed cell height in a table, you are responsible to make sure that the text fits.

If you're concerned about the height, please take a look at the [FitTextInRectangle](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/FitTextInRectangle) example:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
int textHeightInGlyphSpace = bf.getAscent(text) - bf.getDescent(text);
float fontSize = 1000f * fixedHeight / textHeightInGlyphSpace;
```

This example was written in answer to [Correct text position center in rectangle iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909450/correct-text-position-center-in-rectangle-itext)

If you're concerned about the width, then you need to use the `getWidthPoint()` method as explained here: [How to calculate the string width in iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525986/how-to-calculate-the-string-width-in-itext)

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
float width = bf.getWidthPoint("My text", myFontSize);
```

You'll need to make sure that `width` doesn't exceed the width of the cell. To achieve this, you'll need to adjust `myFontSize`.

See my answer to this question: [How to choose the optimal size for a font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966472/choosing-optimal-font-in-the-itextpdf-table)

Comment: is there a way to force to show the text in the table/cell, although the font size is to big and/or the string is to long?

Comment: What would that look like in your opinion? Can you provide a sketch that shows how to put text that is too big into a rectangle that is too small?

Comment: @Clemens I've found an old answer to a question that may be similar to yours. I'll update my answer with a link to that question (and answer).